# navigator is deprecated and has been removed even i don't use navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation

I don't use Navigator in my codes. But I am getting this error.

[image]

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-router-redux": "^0.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does `react-navigation` rely on it? It looks like line 120 of `react-native-implementation` uses it.

Comment: No, it isn't needed.

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Navigator is deprecated !
The other options would be mentioned here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when my IDE automatically added the following lines:

```
import * as AsyncStorage from "react-native";
```

which means: everything in that file, which won't work. Solved it by changing to this:

```
import AsyncStorage from "react-native";
```

Comment: Unbelievable! You saved me a few hours here!

Comment: Thank you very much. in my case its was import * as PropTypes from "react-native";

Answer (score 2):

`Navigator` is no longer supported in react native so this is no longer allowed:

`import { Navigator } from 'react-native'`

Remove the Navigator from 'react-native' imports and substitute it with this: 
`import { Navigator } from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';`

Answer (score 0):

Navigation experimental(Previously `Navigator`) has been removed from React Native and moved to a separate package `react-native-deprecated-custom-components`. It has been deprecated and not recommended. To fix your old code you can perform following steps

1. Install package `react-native-deprecated-custom-components`

   `npm install react-native-deprecated-custom-components --save`
2. Import NavigationExperimental(Previously `Navigator`)

   `import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-comreponents';`
3. Replace `Navigator` with `NavigationExperimental.Navigator`